# Retrofit similar logging

Tags: android, logging, retrofit2

In my rest api i use retrofit + rxJava, for logging request and response i use `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'` i setup it like:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    httpClient.networkInterceptors().clear();
    httpClient.interceptors().add(interceptor);
```

I receive many similar messages with my request and many similar messages with answer like :

```
       --------- beginning of system
12-25 11:51:49.322 741-1237/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=netcraft.golf/.activities.profile.ProfileActivity} from uid 10164 on display 0
12-25 11:51:49.327 741-1237/? V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{307721fc token=Token{ec662ef ActivityRecord{1e4513ce u0 netcraft.golf/.activities.profile.ProfileActivity t1632}}} to stack=1 task=1632 at 1
12-25 11:51:49.335 187-846/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
12-25 11:51:49.358 187-762/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
12-25 11:51:49.358 187-762/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
12-25 11:51:49.358 187-762/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
12-25 11:51:49.360 187-762/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
12-25 11:51:49.376 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.376 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"command":"account_profile","params":{}}
12-25 11:51:49.377 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> END POST (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"command":"account_profile","params":{}}
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> END POST (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"command":"account_profile","params":{}}
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> END POST (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"command":"account_profile","params":{}}
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> END POST (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"command":"account_profile","params":{}}
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> END POST (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.378 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"command":"account_profile","params":{}}
12-25 11:51:49.379 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> END POST (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.379 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.379 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"command":"account_profile","params":{}}
12-25 11:51:49.379 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> END POST (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.379 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.379 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"command":"account_profile","params":{}}
12-25 11:51:49.379 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> END POST (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.379 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1 (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.379 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1 (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.383 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: --> POST /msmapi/lwe HTTP/1.1 (41-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.402 741-759/? V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{18a29eda u0 netcraft.golf/netcraft.golf.activities.profile.ProfileActivity} at 4 of 10 (after Window{5285a5b u0 netcraft.golf/netcraft.golf.activities.MainActivity})
12-25 11:51:49.550 1056-1056/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator: onFinishInput()
12-25 11:51:49.604 741-818/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed netcraft.golf/.activities.profile.ProfileActivity: +274ms
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (242ms, 458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (246ms, 458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (247ms, 458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (247ms)
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 09:52:03 GMT
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 458
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Connection: close
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html,application/json,text/javascript; charset=utf-8
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1451037109511
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1451037109626
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"code":200,"data":{"user":{"id":"64","email":"op@op.op"},"account":{"id":"62","firstName":"ofgj","lastName":"oh","fieldId":"0","handicap":"0","golfCourse":{"id":0,"clubId":0,"title":""}},"address":{"id":"83","countryId":"222","stateId":"","city":"rrrr","address":"","building":"","appartment":"","zip":"","phone1":"","fax1":""},"photo":"http:\/\/golfaction.andrew.dev.ideus.biz\/files\/account\/62\/avatarcdc65eee486869a808af45eef46c62c8.jpeg"},"errors":[]}
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (247ms)
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 09:52:03 GMT
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
12-25 11:51:49.626 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 458
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Connection: close
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html,application/json,text/javascript; charset=utf-8
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1451037109511
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1451037109626
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"code":200}
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (248ms)
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 09:52:03 GMT
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 458
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Connection: close
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html,application/json,text/javascript; charset=utf-8
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1451037109511
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1451037109626
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"code":200}
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (248ms)
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 09:52:03 GMT
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 458
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Connection: close
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html,application/json,text/javascript; charset=utf-8
12-25 11:51:49.627 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1451037109511
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1451037109626
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"code":200}
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (249ms)
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 09:52:03 GMT
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 458
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Connection: close
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html,application/json,text/javascript; charset=utf-8
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1451037109511
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1451037109626
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"code":200}
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (249ms)
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 09:52:03 GMT
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 458
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Connection: close
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html,application/json,text/javascript; charset=utf-8
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1451037109511
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1451037109626
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"code":200}
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (250ms)
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 09:52:03 GMT
12-25 11:51:49.628 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
12-25 11:51:49.629 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
12-25 11:51:49.629 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 458
12-25 11:51:49.629 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Connection: close
12-25 11:51:49.629 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html,application/json,text/javascript; charset=utf-8
12-25 11:51:49.629 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.629 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1451037109511
12-25 11:51:49.629 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1451037109626
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"code":200}
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (253ms)
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2015 09:52:03 GMT
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.39
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 458
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Connection: close
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: Content-Type: text/html,application/json,text/javascript; charset=utf-8
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1451037109511
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1451037109626
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: {"code":200}
12-25 11:51:49.631 26858-27606/? D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (458-byte body)
12-25 11:51:52.538 187-846/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
12-25 11:51:52.539 187-846/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
```

tell me plz is it normal? or i did many requests at same time?